# How to make the URL value in the DBLookup Mediator dynamic using a property in WSO2 Developer Studio?

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-micro-integrator

I am currently working on a project using WSO2 Developer Studio and facing a challenge in trying to make the URL value in the DBLookup Mediator dynamic. I need to configure the DBLookup to access an external database, and the URL value must be dynamically fed through a property.

I've tried the following two ways but it doesn't work as expected:

**[1]**

```xml
<property name="database.url" expression="json-eval($.url)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<dblookup>
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
            <url expression="get-property('database.url')"/>
            <user>test</user>
            <password>12345</password>
        </pool>
    </connection>
</dblookup>
```

**[2]**

```xml
<property name="database.url" expression="json-eval($.url)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<dblookup>
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
            <url>{get-property('database.url')}</url>
            <user>test</user>
            <password>12345</password>
        </pool>
    </connection>
</dblookup>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP endpoints can be dynamically constructed using uri template. Create properties name starting with uri.var prefix and define the uri template to refer those created properties e.g if property name is uri.var.context then uri template cane be defined as http:://localhost/{uri.var.context}

Try this:

```
<property name="uri.var.database" expression="json-eval($.url)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<dblookup>
<connection>
    <pool>
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
        <url>{uri.var.database}</url>
        <user>test</user>
        <password>12345</password>
    </pool>
</connection>
```

There are more use-cases here:
https://medium.com/@Jenananthan/wso2-esb-construct-dynamic-urls-67fad2f6d34c

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work that way either. When running it returns the following error:
 ERROR {DBLookupMediator} - {api:HelloWorld} SQL Exception occurred while executing statement : select * from text against DataSource : {uri.var.database} org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL '{uri.var.database}'